# How to properly set up cart price rule for multiple SKUs?

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, magento2.2

I have set up these rules for my cart. And the cart is filled with 11 of the same product, or 5 of one variation and 6 of another. Either way, no discount is applied:

[image: settings1]

[image: settings2]

[image: settings3]

[image]

[image]

Do I have errors in my configuration?
Or am I using this feature incorrectly?

I am currently using Magento CE 2.2.0. The default prices for these two variations of products are $1.00 and $5.00

Comment: It seems like your main issue is showing  2 qty for 11 quantities.

Comment: @Anime can you expand on what you mean? I don't really see where you are meaning to highlight this issue. Thanks.

Comment: On our store adding same 10 product  counts to 10 not 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can't see from here, you need click "View and Edit Cart" then go to cart page to see discount.